# Search for False advertising/drug name associated with patient complaint of false advertising

Tags: government, openfda

I'm looking for a way to search the OpenFDA databse for a patients claim of false advertising. I would then like to return the results of the search ion which the Drugs are noted with that claim.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Joe is correct here. We don't currently offer data on patient claim of false advertising. In our scope for the future, we plan to offer data on product recalls and product labels. We're definitely listening to the community, though, and will add patient claims of false advertising to our list of potential datasets for the future!

Sean Herron, openFDA Team Member

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the OpenFDA service has that data at this time. Right now, the only data source they have is

> This is the openFDA API endpoint for adverse drug events. An adverse
>   event is submitted to the FDA to report any undesirable experience
>   associated with the use of a drug, including serious drug side
>   effects, product use errors, product quality problems, and therapeutic
>   failures.

From a little googling, it seems like you're interested in the [Office of Prescription Drug Promotion](http://www.fda.gov/aboutfda/centersoffices/officeofmedicalproductsandtobacco/cder/ucm090142.htm). I didn't see any online access to the complaints.